# Removing reference blocks per website in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, blocks, multi-website, reference

If I add the following to any default.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" />
```

The Mini Cart is removed. However my question is how do I only remove the reference block for a particular website or store?

At the moment I have a separate theme for each website but wondered if I could set anything on the reference block to enable me to do it direct from 1 default.xml

Answer (score 0):

To remove particular reference blocks by website or store you need to create store configuration **Yes/No** value field using custom module.

then use like below"  `<referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true" ifconfig="sectionname/groupname/filedname" />`